# PHP SOAP content type

Tags: php, soap, content-type

I'm trying in PHP to get response from SOAP service running on Microsoft Server, I have:

```
$this->client = new SoapClient(
   'https://url.com/EmployeeService.svc?wsdl', 
   array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)
);
$this->client->__soapCall("GetEmployees", ['token']);
```

But I get Error:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IEmployeeService/GetEmployees"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

So I change version to SOAP_1_1, but then I get error:

> looks like we got no XML document

Do I have to change something next? Or what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does the response look normal? Can you post an example of the response?

Comment: Because of this error I do not get response. But service is good, when I use function __getFunctions(), i get response with all functions. Problem is in the content type of my request in "not magic functions".

Comment: What is version of your SOAP server?

Comment: @MateuszWoźniak I dont have documentation to the server (i hope i will get it someday), but I think, that it is 1.1 because of the expecting content type text/xml.